# Display a Viewpager that scrolls together with a RecyclerView

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I want to display a Viewpager that scrolls up when the RecyclerView that I have placed below scrolls up.

The information displayed in the RecyclerView depends on the page displayed in the Viewpager. Above the Viewpager there is a Toolbar.

This is the layout I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".main.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/text_white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.pixplicity.multiviewpager.MultiViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:background="@color/black"
                app:matchChildWidth="@+id/page"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Note: MultiViewPager is a ViewPager that displays part of previous and next pages.

When a page is selected, I replace the framelayout with a Fragment that contains a RecyclerView. The layout of the fragment is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyView"
        style="@style/no_data"
        android:text="@string/movements_no_data"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Althought it seems to work in Kitkat, when I try it on Marshmallow the behaviour is strange: the scroll moves the Viewpager in a different way that the RecyclerView.

Note 2: in Kitkat I have to force the scroll to reset its position when the app starts, because the scroll is initially displaced from the TOP. The code I use for resetting is:

```
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
        }
    });
```

Any other layout suggestion or idea about how to implement this layout would be appreciated.

Comment: Add the required layout as a header to your recyclerView

Comment: Edited as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by setting the ViewPager inside a CollapsingToolbarLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <com.pixplicity.multiviewpager.MultiViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pager_margin_top"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:matchChildWidth="@+id/page"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:shadowColor="#000"
                android:shadowDx="2"
                android:shadowDy="2"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView.
That being said, you don't need that if inside of the scrolling view you use RecyclerView. You can assign the behaviour of app bar scroll to RecyclerView directly and it will manage the scrolling and collapsing of appbar.
Note, that if you do use NestedScrollView, you will probably need to set it to fill view port for better performance and look.